# Выполнение нескольких скриптов на странице

Tags: javascript, html, html5, xml, mathjax

К документу страницы в Blogger подключены два скрипта. В теге `<head>`:

```
<script type ='text/x-mathjax-config'>
        MathJax.Hub.Config({
        tex2jax: {inlineMath: [[&#39;$&#39;,&#39;$&#39;], [&#39;\\(&#39;,&#39;\\)&#39;]]}
        });
</script>
<script src='http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML' type='text/javascript'> </script>
```

Этот скрипт отвечает за отрисовку математических формул.
Следующий скрипт отвечает за отображение схем. Он содержится на некоторых страницах в блоке отображения сообщения.

```
<script src="https://www.draw.io/embed2.js?s=flowchart&amp;" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

На данный момент на страницах, где используется оба скрипта, первый из блока `<head>` игнорируется и выполняется только второй. Необходимо, чтобы на странице выполнялись эти два скрипта. И корректно отображался контент, использующих оба этих скрипта, на одной странице.

В консоли браузера выходят следующие ошибки:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Startup' of undefined
at Object.StartupHook (MathJax.js:19)
at Object.loadComplete (MathJax.js:19)
at Function.execute (MathJax.js:19)
at cb (MathJax.js:19)

 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'MathEvents' of undefined
    at TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML.js?V=2.7.0:55
    at Function.execute (MathJax.js:19)
    at cb (MathJax.js:19)
    at Object.Execute (MathJax.js:19)
    at Object.ExecuteHooks (MathJax.js:19)
    at Function.execute (MathJax.js:19)
    at cb (MathJax.js:19)
    at Object.Execute (MathJax.js:19)
    at Object.Post (MathJax.js:19)
    at Function.execute (MathJax.js:19)
```

Comment: В вашем вопросе я вижу три тэга объявления скрипта, не понятно где второй и что игнорируется..

Comment: Игнорируется тот, что в теге head

Comment: http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/start.html#tex-and-latex-input - в документации в премере скрипт подключается с использованием `async` атрибута. Попробуйте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просмотрев ошибки браузера можно заметить, что они связаны с одновременным выполнением отрисовки схем. Т.е. MathJax пытается прочесть весь код страницы, в том числе и не загруженную полностью схему. В связи с этим возникают ошибки парсинга скриптом MathJax. Чтобы этого избежать добавляем в конец шаблона, перед `</body>` следующий код:

```
<script>
setTimeout(function() {
   var script = document.createElement('script');
   script.src = 'https://www.draw.io/embed2.js?s=flowchart&amp;';
   script.type = 'text/javascript';
   document.head.appendChild(script);
}, 2000);
</script>
```

Это позволит выполнение после скрипта MathJax. Сама отрисовка схемы будет происходить только на тех страницах, где она присутствует. И это позволить избежать дублирование кода отрисовки схем на всех страницах.